# SQL Statement Only latest entry of the day

Tags: sql, h2, greatest-n-per-group

seems it is too long ago that I needed create own SQL Statements. I have a table (GAS_COUNTER) with timestamps (TS) and values (VALUE).
There are hundreds of entries per day, but I only need the latest of the day. I tried different ways but never get what I need.

**Edit**

Thanks for the fast replies, but some do not meet my needs (I need the latest value of each day in the table) and some don't work. My best own statement was:

```
select distinct (COUNT),
 from
  (select
   extract (DAY_OF_YEAR from TS) as COUNT,
   extract (YEAR from TS) as YEAR,
   extract (MONTH from TS) as MONTH,
   extract (DAY from TS) as DAY,
   VALUE as VALUE
 from GAS_COUNTER
order by COUNT)
```

but the value is missing. If I put it in the first select all rows return. (logical correct as every line is distinct)
Here an example of the Table content:

```
TS                      VALUE  
2015-07-25 08:47:12.663 0.0
2015-07-25 22:50:52.155 2.269999999552965
2015-08-10 11:18:07.667 52.81999999284744
2015-08-10 20:29:20.875 53.27999997138977
2015-08-11 10:27:21.49  54.439999997615814
```

**2nd Edit and solution**

```
select TS, VALUE from GAS_COUNTER  
where TS in (
    select max(TS) from GAS_COUNTER group by extract(DAY_OF_YEAR from TS)
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one would give you the very last record:

```
select top 1 * from GAS_COUNTER order by TS desc
```

Here is one that would give you last records for every day:

```
select VALUE from GAS_COUNTER 
where TS in (
    select max(TS) from GAS_COUNTER group by to_date(TS,'yyyy-mm-dd')
)
```

Depending on the database you are using you might need to replace/adjust to_date(TS,'yyyy-mm-dd') function. Basically it should extract date-only part from the timestamp.

Comment: Thanks but I need the last value from each day.

Comment: I added one that would extract last value from each day

Comment: Thanks for your help, but one of my problems is, that H2 does not support a lot of functions that I know from oracle and mysql. In your statement to_date is not supported (but on the roadmap of H2)
But I changed the group by to extract (DAY_OF_YEAR from TS) and it works. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Select the max value for the timestamp.

```
select MAX(TS), value -- or whatever other columns you want from the record
from GAS_COUNTER
group by value
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but like many other (own) tries this generates an error. VALUE must be part of the ?GROUP BY? list. Is max doing a group? Seems like H2 is really different to oracle and mysql, the databases I worked with before.

Comment: Also, quick question. Does the table just have two columns (TS and Value)?

Comment: There is also a third column STATE, that is always 1. Your statement returns all rows.  I got a working statement from Anton. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would window the data and give you the last value on the day - but what happens if you get two TS the same? Which one do you want?

```
select *
from (  select distinct cast( TS as date ) as dt
        from GAS_COUNTER ) as gc1       --  distinct days
    cross apply (
        select top 1 VALUE      --  last value on the date.
        from GAS_COUNTER as gc2
        where gc2.TS < dateadd( day, 1, gc1.dt )
          and gc2.TS >= gc1.dt
        order by gc2.TS desc
        ) as x
```

Comment: This way looks interesting, but it don't work. H2 claims cross apply as syntax error.