# How to get the LATEST count of different items (based on date)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have this table:

| date | itemID | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 | 3 |
| 2021-01-03 | 1 | NULL |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 2 | NULL |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 | NULL |

I want it to return like this:

| itemID | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |

Basically what I want to happen is to return the LATEST count of the itemID... The one whose count has a value but only pick the highest date... the tricky part is the date differs per item...

I haven't made it close when I tried myself, I tried to GROUP BY date, itemID but I can't  make it work... been stuck with these for a day now...

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if you also add the row `(2021-01-02, 3, null)`?

Comment: And I assume you want to skip/ignore NULL values, right? You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33694714/sql-statement-only-latest-entry-of-the-day/33695004).

Comment: @jarlk, I use mysql and the expected result for that should be null although it is expected the the count has a value at some point in the past...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `not exists`. Based on your expected output, I am assuming you want to skip `null`

```
select itemId, count
from t a
where count is not null and
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t b 
                  where b.count is not null and b.itemId=a.itemId and a.date<b.date)
```

Can also be expressed using a `join`

```
select a.itemId, a.count
from t a
join (select itemId, max(date) as date 
      from t where count is not null 
      group by itemId) b on b.itemId=a.itemId and a.date=b.date
```

MySQl supports `semi joins` using tuples so you could also do

```
select itemId, count
from t 
where (itemId,date) in (select itemId,max(date) 
                        from t where count is not null 
                        group by itemId)
```

A variation of above could also be implemented using a `correlated subquery`

```
select itemId, count
from t a
where date = (select max(date) 
              from t where count is not null and itemId=a.itemId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemID ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
    WHERE count IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT date, itemID, count
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: does this work for mysql? my phpadmin says it doesn't recognize the statement WITH

Comment: @jove0610 . . . MySQL has supported this syntax for *years*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's some sort of PHP thing AFAIK.  The other answer can be used if this is the really the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.itemId = t.itemId and t2.count is not null
               );
```